# check excel every cell is empty or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

**help mew check the excel cell is empty or not if empty han show the error with column number**

```
string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
string conString = string.Empty;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
switch (extension)
{
  case ".xls":
    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
    break;
  case ".xlsx":
    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
    break;
}
conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
  excel_con.Open();
  DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();
  using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", excel_con))
  {
    oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
  }
  excel_con.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand where you want to check for an empty cell. In the Excel file or the `DataTable` `dtExcelData` collection. Given the code, I would assume it would be easier to “check” for the empty cells in the `dtExcelData` `DataTable.` However, It is unclear “what” you want to do if a cell is empty. Do you want to do something in the Excel file? You should clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: yes when upload a excel in datatable and then check the excel cells is empty or not

Comment: want to check empty cell from dtExcelData

Comment: Hmm… to check each cell in the `dtExcelData` table, you would loop through each row, then loop through each column and check each cell. There is a plethora of examples on how to do this. I am guessing I may be missing something. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess basiclly you can iterate through dtExcelData,

```
foreach(DataRow row in dtExcelData.Rows)
{
     // Here you can make a condition to find empty or null cells per row.
}
```